# track deletion and insertion of lines

Tags: buffers, cursor

The marks in `vim` knows the deletion and insertion of lines before it and their positions will keep updated. Is there a way to achieve these pragmatically?

I am running an async task which is supposed to update the **current line** when the task finishes. Here the **current line** means the cursor line at the time the task is launched. After launching it, I may need to move the cursor around; make modifications to the buffer. How can I get the correct position when the task finishes **without using a mark**? If marks are used, they may be accidentally reset by user or by other third party plugins.

---

### example

Given the text:

```
line1
line2
fix me please
line4
line5
```

Assume my cursor is now at line 3, I am going to run `:Fixme` which is to replace `fix me please` with `line3` but at a much later time.

If during this waiting period, I delete `line1` or inserte more lines before line 3, I hope `:Fixme` is aware of this change and still updates the line `fix me please`. How to achieve this?

Comment: when you launch your task, store the current cursor position in an extra variable.

Comment: Thank you @ChristianBrabandt. I added an example there. Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: It depends on your async task. When calling the async job, you should store the current cursor line number. However, that won't work when the line above has been deleted, than those will be off.

Comment: If an mark is set over there, and lines are inserted or deleted, the mark position will follow. Is it possible to exploit this behavior?

Comment: Sure, set a mark then :)

Comment: I just want my plugin to be more robust. There is no way to prevent the user and other plugins to remove my mark; and I don't want to change other plugin's marks either.

Comment: I would be the best if any autocmds can be used to recalculate the position, like what the mark system does. But I didn't find one.

Comment: That is not possible. adjusting the marks is done internally by Vim. As far as I know, there is no other possibility to have the line numbers adjust automatically. (BTW: You can always restore the previous mark if it was set).

Comment: Restore previous mark is easy. But to prevent my marks to be reset is impossible. :( Any way, thanks for your time. Do you think it reasonable to request this feature to be exposed to vim scripting? Provided the mark system already has done the things for updating, it might not be difficult.

Comment: Sure, you can request it. By coincidence, Bram just asked [what specifically plugin authors need](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/3573). You can mention your request there (or create a new wishlist ticket). I cannot promise that this will be implemented soon however.

Comment: Thank you for having suggested a wonderful place to me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, only *marks* are automatically adapted to changes in the buffer by Vim. You can record arbitrary positions via `getpos()`, but these would have to be adapted to changes on your own (and that is not generally possible if you have no control over the changes that are done).

Plugins usually "reserve" some marks for their use, either by documenting it (*"this mapping uses mark z"*), or by taking unused marks (cp. [ingo#plugin#marks#Reserve()](https://github.com/inkarkat/vim-ingo-library/blob/3307d27ffd15d906355cefcb48f1304ef4fb1379/autoload/ingo/plugin/marks.vim#L82) in my [ingo-library plugin](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4433)).

It indeed would be great if there were a low-level function to use "unnamed marks" for plugins, similar to the distinction between `:match` (user) and `matchadd()` (plugins). You can raise this idea in [this poll](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/3573).

Comment: thank you very much for explaining this to me and also suggesting the way to go. I will draft a proposal later.